# CSS conflict with a:link and a:visited in 2 class/id

Tags: css

i have problem with a:visited and a:link for 2 class/id.

```
#title a:link, #title a:visited {
color:black;
}

#PageCounter a:link, #PageCounter a:visited {
color:green;
}
```

output:
all link of #title and #PageCounter are color black.

but i want #PageCounter all on color green.

i did tried test with "#title:visted" and "#title :visited" and "#title visited"... is not work. =/

(example)HTML format:

```
<div id="title"><a href="#">Hello World</a></div><br><br>
<font id="PageCounter"><a href="?page=x">1,2,3,4,5,6,7,....</a></font>
```

Comment: can you show the html this corresponds to?

Comment: your demo code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nPztA/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are the anchor tags direct descendants of the elements with the IDs 'title' and 'PageCounter'? If so, you might want to use the child selector:

```
#title > a:link, #title > a:visited {
    ...
}
#PageCounter > a:link, #PageCounter > a:visited {
    ...
}
```

The selectors you show in your question will affect any anchor elements within the elements identified by 'title' and 'PageCounter', regardless of how deeply nested they are. It might be possible that one of those selectors is 'hiding' the other. Using the child selector makes it more explicit.